# Inheritance in python 2.7

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-2.7

I am attempting to build a framework for parsing a very specific text structure.
The structure that I am processing is rich and has a known schema, similar to xml.
I am attempting to build an framework to do the parsing. The text has various sections and I anticipate that more sections code be added in the future. To Compensate, I am attempting to build a series of derived classed that can be swapped in or out as needed.

I thought everything was going as planned, until I started coding up the first derived class.
The base class has some functionality inside of `__init__` that I was expecting that I would get for free in all of the concrete derived classes. That however, doesn't seem to be the case at all.

Here is a simple example to illustrate my problem:
I would expect the output to be:

> ['memberA', 'memberB', 'memberC'],
>       ['DerivedA', 'DerivedB', 'DerivedC']

```
class base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        members = [attr for attr in dir(self) if not callable(attr) and not attr.startswith("__")]
        print members

class test(base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.memberA = None
        self.memberB = None
        self.memberC = None


class test2(test):
    def __init__(self):
        self.DerivedA = None
        self.DerivedB = None
        self.DerivedC = None

t = test()
t2 = test2()
```

Can someone please explain to my, why the print functionality is not working as I expect it?

EDIT:
in light of the answer below: I now have this question:

What if base.__init(self) instead looked like:

```
class base(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
```

would I have to define the derived class as:

```
class test(base):
    def __init__(self, text):
        base.__init__(self, text)
```

I was hoping to at least get the parameter object referance for free

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python, you must call the base class's `__init__` explicitly inside `test.__init__`:

```
class test(base):
    def __init__(self):
        base.__init__(self)
```

Or, if you wish to support multiple inheritance, use `super`:

```
class test(base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(test, self).__init__()
```

---

If the `base.__init__` looks like

```
class base(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
```

then `test.__init__` should indeed look like

```
class test(base):
    def __init__(self, text):
        base.__init__(self, text)
```

See Guido van Rossum's blog for [why `self` is explicit in Python](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html).

---

PS. [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends using CapWords for class names.

Answer (score 0):

you are overwriting **init** in test2

following code will complete overwrite **init** in test. so there is no longer a print int the **init** function.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.DerivedA = None
    self.DerivedB = None
    self.DerivedC = None
```